# How to use an imported node module

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm fairly new to node.js and trying to get it to work. So far importing a module using `npm install (package name)` works fine and i can see the module in the node_modules folder and package.json.

For example: I tried installing WebFontLoader https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfontloader Just install it using `npm install webfontloader` and add the script to the html.

```
 var WebFont = require('webfontloader');

 WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
    }
  });
```

However I get an error message `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

I don't understand what I'm missing, is there something I need to include?

Comment: What version of node do you have installed, and how are you initializing the script?

Comment: How are you running the script where this code is?

Comment: I'm using node v11.14.0 (npm v6.11.3). The script is implemented in the footer.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research it turns out `require` is not a function used in native JS. Another module is needed to "translate" this function to be used in browsers. In my case http://browserify.org/ was the answer. After following the instructions a bundled script is being outputted `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` that can be used in your website.